# Calculating the number of rounds required to complete a tournament

Tags: php

We're running an heads-up tournament on our website, where the goal is to keep playing until a single winner remains. This works much the same as e.g. a tennis tournament bracket.

However, it only works perfectly if the number of participants is a power of 2, and this happens only rarely, so most of the time the first step is to play a round where some number of participants get a free win (a "bye") into the next round, in order to get the number of players down to the closest power of 2.

Everything works just fine, but I have a nagging suspicion that the part that calculates the number of rounds required to complete the tournament can be heavily improved. Here's the code I'm using to calculate it:

```
function totalRounds($participants)
{
    $closestLowerPow2 = pow(2, (strlen(decbin($participants)) - 1));

    $roundsWithoutByes = (int) log($closestLowerPow2, 2);

    return $participants == $closestLowerPow2
        ? $roundsWithoutByes
        : $roundsWithoutByes + 1;
}
```

So the length of the binary minus 1 is the closest power. Use log to find out how many rounds that requires, since if e.g. there are 8 participants, then there are 3 rounds to play, as 2³ = 8. Finally, add a round if we need to have a round with byes before that.

Is there a smarter way I'm overlooking? :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I feel like an idiot but I finally figured out why it seemed like there should be an obvious solution - one hour after posting, and three after starting to think about it. If I'm not allowed to post the answer myself, please let me know and I'll remove it.

```
function totalRounds($participants)
{
    return strlen(decbin($participants - 1));
}
```

The logic goes as follows: each bit in a string representation of the number of participants as a binary can be seen as a doubling of the number of participants, as long as the total number is a power of 2.

Then, by the same logic, each bit (except for the left-most one) can be seen as the reverse - a halving of the number of participants. And this is exactly what we want: each round, half of the players should be eliminated.

If we need to assign byes, that basically means we need to do one more round than that - so we can just use the string length straight away. But if we don't, then we need to disregard the left-most bit.

So if we start by subtracting one from the number of participants, that means that e.g. 8 participants = 1000 in binary turns into 7 = 111, which requires three rounds. For 9-15 participants, the string length would not change, so it's still correct. And for 16, the same logic applies as did to 8 - and so on.

Comment: This works fine for `$participants ≥ 2`, which will probably be good enough for practical applications. For 0 or 1 participant, the number of rounds should be 0.

Comment: Thanks, good point! Although, yeah, for 0-1 participants you'd probably just cancel the contest instead. :p